# maxlength=5 not working if input type=number

Tags: javascript, html, maxlength

This is frustrating!

When the input type is `text` and I gave `maxlength` as 5, it is not allowing me to enter more than 5 characters

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="5" />
```

If I gave input type as `number` and I gave `maxlength` as 5, it is allowing more than 5 digits?

```
<input type="number" maxlength="5" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

Am I missing something?

PS: This is for mobile responsive site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Answer. It's so simple!

```
<input type="number" id="nbr"/>

<input type="text"  maxlength="5" />

$(document).on('keypress','#nbr', function(e){
if($(this).val().length >= 5)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `maxlength` use `max`

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10000" />
```

**Update**

Small jQuery plugin

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.maxlength = function (length) {
        return this.on('keydown', function () {
            var maxlength = length || parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'), 10) ;
            if (maxlength && $(this).val().length >= maxlength) {
                $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, maxlength - 1));
            }
        });
    };
}($));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/760j75bk/13/)

Comment: Appreciate your work +1 ..This will work in mobile? Because you have used keypress right?

Answer (score 2):

try using `max`...

```
<input type="number" max="99999" />
```

**EDIT**: Showing Validation

```
<form id='FormValidation'>
<input id="myNum" type="number" min="1" max="99999" />
<input type="text"  maxlength="5" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Try adding a number greater than **99999** and hitting submit, check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/760j75bk/1/).

This jquery could help too...

```
$('#myNum').keyup( function(e){
    var max = $('#myNum').attr('max').length;
    if ($(this).val().length >= max) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/760j75bk/   in input type text, it wont allow to type more than 5 characters but in input type number, it is not...

Comment: in input type text, it stops typing after you entered the 6th character right? I need the same to be applied to input type number..

Comment: If you use the arrows in your fiddle, you'll see that it can only go up as far as the max attribute.  If you type, sure, you can pass that, but with validation the form will not be valid.  Are you using a validation framework?

Comment: No..I need the user wont allow more than 5 characters..validations are there if there is nothing entered in the input field..otherwise patterns are also accepted.....like....<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="5" but it is not displaying only number keypad :( that's the problem

Comment: Check the updated fiddle, when you hit submit, you'll see the validation error.

Comment: This one I m expecting!

Comment: @TRGWII: you have used ondomready....how can I use it inside the script? can I use that code inside ready function?

Comment: @UIDesigner Be aware that input event not supported for all browsers http://goo.gl/JBd9v6

Answer (score 1):

replace  `maxlength`  with `max`

```
 // Max Length = 5
<input type="number" max="99999" />
// length between 1 to 5
<input type="number" min="1" max="99999" />
```

Comment: No. I 'm asking the length not not the limit..there is a difference between length and limit

Comment: Please see this fiddle...jsfiddle.net/760j75bk in input type text, it wont allow to type more than 5 characters but in input type number, it is not... it stops typing after you entered the 6th character right?

Comment: Why should you use type="Number" if you have to type using keyboard than take it type='text'......if number than see attached arrow increment it's go on 999... Using JQuery you do that things

Comment: @UIDesigner  Here is your Answer on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/higunjan/jAYEt/119/

Answer (score 0):

And you can add a max attribute that will specify the highest possible number that you may insert

```
<input type="number" max="999" />
```

if you add both a max and a min value you can specify the range of allowed values:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" />
```